# MATLAB Access Classreg

Tags: matlab

So, I want to be able to look at (read: copy) MATLAB's NonLinearModel method of printing the regression results to the screen such as this.

```
Nonlinear regression model:
    y ~ (alpha1 - alpha2*t^0.5)

Estimated Coefficients:
              Estimate     SE            tStat     pValue    
    alpha1       1.0253     0.0082253    124.66    4.8823e-24
    alpha2    0.0061783    0.00073277    8.4314    4.4834e-07


Number of observations: 17, Error degrees of freedom: 15
Root Mean Squared Error: 0.0165
R-Squared: 0.826,  Adjusted R-Squared 0.814
F-statistic vs. constant model: 71.1, p-value = 4.48e-07
```

I want to be able to leave off the tStat and pValue columns, and replace the information below with AIC and other metrics I'm going to use for comparison. Is there any easy way to get at this code? I'm looking in NonLinearModel.m and I think the 'methods' are 'hidden'? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file using:

```
>> open classreg.regr.modelutils.tstats
```

This will open "tstats.m".

The path of that file on your drive can be a acccessed using:

```
>> which classreg.regr.modelutils.tstats
```

In this folder there are all the other m-files which belong to this class.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to see all the 'modelutils.~'? I want to see how the table is printed so that I can go about making a similar table.